# Open new route with same filter applied

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my angular app I have a ng-repeated list with a custom filter.

I would like to provide the possibility to open the filtered list in a new browser window with a print layout.

Is there any way to apply the current filter to a route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a service to store the state of the filter in local storage. Let the other window read this state from the local storage.

Or pass the complete state as a query string in the url of the new window where you rebuild the filter. But this is ugly, makes no good use of Angular and is not done by all the cool kids.

Comment: Used a service to store the state of the filter in local storage. Like the cool kids do. Thanks.